How do you address yourself in a cover letter for faculty applications if you are not affiliated with any institutions?
I have just finished my last postdoctoral role and I am  now unemployed because my visa runs out, so I have to go back to my home country.
However, my faculty application effort is still ongoing. At the top of cover letters, I currently write

[my name] 
Theoretical chemist 
[My home address] 
[my email]

followed by date and address of the institution I am applying to.
What do you think of that? Do you have better alternatives?

What you write looks fine, but explain, somewhere but briefly, that you have just finished a postdoc at institution A and have returned home for visa reasons. It shouldn't be a problem.
Your CV will probably show some of this information, of course, but a brief mention in the cover letter does no harm.
